# Using Authorize.net SDK CIM - SOAP In C# Transaction ID, Invoice Number,Authorization Code is blank in Live mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, soap, authorize.net

I am implementing CIM-SOAP method using authorize.Net SDK for asp.Net(C#) technology with production server details (LoginID & TransactionKey) and live mode.

I have created customer profile & customer payment profile using Create Customer() and AddCreditCard() methods of customer gateway class respectively.

I had authorized and captured the transactions using generated customer profile ID and payment profile ID using Authorize() and Authorize And Capture () methods of customer gateway class ,receiving response code as ok & successful but transaction ID and invoice number, card number, authorization code as blank.

These transactions are reflecting in merchant account on authorize.net.

Below is code(C#)  for authorize only  & authorize & capture transaction and corresponding response.
 where CustomerProfileID="154266977" & payment Profile Id ="146233337"

**1) Using Authorize Method :**

```
CustomerGateway cg = new CustomerGateway(AuthNetLoginID, AuthNetTransKey, ServiceMode.Live);

IGatewayResponse igr = cg.Authorize("154266977", "146233337", Convert.ToDecimal(0.5));
```

Method Response :

> Amount :0 Approved :false Authorization Code :"" Card Number :""
>   Invoice Number :"" Message :"" Response Code :"OkI00001Successful"
>   TransactionID:""

**2) Using Authorize & Capture :**

```
CustomerGateway cg = new CustomerGateway(AuthNetLoginID, AuthNetTransKey, ServiceMode.Live);

IGatewayResponse igr1 = cg.AuthorizeAndCapture("154266977", "146233337", Convert.ToDecimal(0.5));
```

Method Response :

> Amount :0 Approved :false Authorization Code :"" Card Number :""
>   Invoice Number :"" Message :"" Response Code :"OkI00001Successful"
>   TransactionID :""

Please kindly help,
Thanks

Comment: For best results, make sure you restate your question in the body of your post to make it clear what your asking. You can always update your question. Welcome to stack overflow, recommended reading: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Could you format your code using "Code Sample" buttons ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you got a response on Authorize.net community forum. So I will forward this on to here for the rest of the stack overflow community:

http://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/Integration-and-Testing/Transaction-ID-Invoice-Number-is-blank-in-Live-using-authorize/td-p/50566

"It a known bug with the SDK...."